# How to setup the data structure for top navigation

Tags: information-architecture

For menu like this one:

https://www.logitech.com/en-us

- labels at the top
- on hover, submenu opens
- submenu can include subcategories labels as well as some images or custom components
- each submenu may be different from others

[image: example menu]

I use React/NextJS to implement UI of the menu itself. Am totally new to Sitecore and was wandering what data structures should I use or how to structure dependencies in Sitecore to make it managable from CMS standpoint but also not use replacement column spots everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this structure that includes your Main Navigation and sub-navigations. You can start with this and modify it as per your needs.

```
Main Navigation 
   - Shop (Template Name: First Level Navigation, Fields: Title)
        - Mice (Template Name: Second Level Navigation, Fields: Title, Image, Link)
            - Navigation Item (Template Name: Navigation Item, Fields: Title, Link)
            - Navigation Item (Template Name: Navigation Item, Fields: Title, Link)
        - Keyboard (Template Name: Second Level Navigation, Fields: Title, Image, Link)
            - Navigation Item (Template Name: Navigation Item, Fields: Title, Link)
            - Navigation Item (Template Name: Navigation Item, Fields: Title, Link)
        - Webcam & Audio (Template Name: Second Level Navigation, Fields: Title, Image, Link)
            - Navigation Item (Template Name: Navigation Item, Fields: Title, Link)
        - Mobile Solution (Template Name: Second Level Navigation, Fields: Title, Image, Link)
            - Navigation Item (Template Name: Navigation Item, Fields: Title, Link)
   - Discover 
        - Item 
            - Navigation Item 
        - Item 
            - Navigation Item 
        - Item 
            - Navigation Item 
   - Business 
        - Item 
            - Navigation Item 
        - Item 
            - Navigation Item 
   - Support 
        - Item 
            - Navigation Item
        - Item 
            - Navigation Item
        - Item 
            - Navigation Item
```

Hope this helps.